# How to convert datetime to date without using convert function in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm trying to convert `datetime` to `date` using convert function. But it is taking large as there is huge data in the table.

Is there any other way to do this without using convert function in less time.

Query:

```
Select * 
from address 
where convert(date,record-created_date) between '6/29/2016' and '6/30/2016'
```

Comment: Usually better to just adjust your constants so that the time portion is irrelevant.

Comment: Assuming you've examined you plans, indexes etc etc, read this http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea

Comment: What data types are the columns involved?

Comment: There can be different solutions in dependence of type of `record-created_date` field.

Comment: The data type is datetime for record_created_date

Comment: DATEADD/DATEDIFF is working when I ran select statement only. But it is taking similar time as convert when I used it in stored procedure.

Comment: If it is datetime then you needn't use convert and the problem rather in indexes tnan in convertation.

Comment: You should edit the title since it doesn't describe what you want... - something like 'how to filter a large table by date portion of a datetime'

Answer (score 2):

You can simply remove `CONVERT` function as following query, so no time is spent for converting, but instead you have to add time to your `[record-created_date]` column in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    [address]
WHERE   [record-created_date] BETWEEN '6/29/2016 00:00:00:000' AND '6/30/2016 23:59:59:999'
```

Answer (score 1):

With SQL 2008 you can use `CAST`:

```
select cast(record-created_date as date)
```

In older versions, you can use `DATEADD/DATEDIFF`:

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, record-created_date))
```

Comment: Be careful as `CAST` is mostly sargable, `DATEADD` is mostly not.

Answer (score 1):

You can define 2 constants in advanced, thus avoid using convert function on the column:

```
declare @min_date datetime
declare @max_date datetime

set @min_date = convert(datetime, '06/29/2016', 101)

-- Max date needs to be the next date of your end date
set @max_date = convert(datetime, '06/30/2016', 101) + 1

Select * 
from address 
where record-created_date >= @min_date 
and record-created_date < @max_date
```

Answer (score 1):

Just omit the conversion and add one day to the end date:

```
where record_created_date between '6/29/2016' and '7/1/2016'
```

This is interpreted as `<= '7/1/2016 0:00'`, so use this short form only if is okay that midnight of the following day is included. Otherwise use the long form:

```
where record_created_date >= '6/29/2016' and record_created_date < '7/1/2016'
```

...or add the time:

```
where record_created_date between '6/29/2016' and '6/30/2016 23:59:59.999'
```

Btw., I think it is better to use the date format '2016-06-29' for hardcoded dates.

Anyway the main reason for being slow is most likely a missing index for this column.